AL report Date filtering Business central Development | Date restriction on RequestFilterFields
​
​
Hello, struggling to learn with AL. I got simple report that is supposed to show data in table.
RequestFilterFields = "Transfer Order Date";


I was hoping to use requestfilterfields to sort out my data. However, there should be minimum value for date value. In this example, 30/06/2024. Report shouldn't show data prior to 01.07.2024.
So, i added this trigger:
trigger OnPreDataItem()
            begin
                SetRange("Transfer Order Date", DMY2Date(1, 7, 2024), Today);
            end;


​
Apparently, this trigger always shows "01.07.2024 ---> Today", despite I enter filter value for the Transfer Order Date.
​What can i do to achieve what i am looking for?

The value entered on the request page is overwritten by the logic in the OnPreDataItem trigger. Take a look at the documentation that illustrates the general overall flow when a report is invoked: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-report-triggers?tabs=current%2Crdlc#overall-report-trigger-and-operations
In the case you have provided, the following would only apply the SetRange filter if there is not already a filter on the "Transfer Order Date" field.
trigger OnPreDataItem()
begin
    if GetFilter("Transfer Order Date") = '' then
        SetRange("Transfer Order Date", DMY2Date(1, 7, 2024), Today());
end;

EDIT: I have re-read your question and come to the conclusion that my answer above is not accurate.
Since you wanted to set a minimum filter regardless of whether the user enters a custom filter or not, the following use of the FilterGroup method is what you are looking for:
trigger OnPreDataItem()
begin
    FilterGroup(10);
    SetFilter("Transfer Order Date", '>=%1', DMY2Date(1, 7, 2024));
    FilterGroup(0);
end;

Please note that this type of hidden filter is not visible to the user. Display a note to inform the user that the data has been filtered, otherwise there is a risk that the question will appear later.
For detailed information about FilterGroup see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/methods-auto/record/record-filtergroup-method
